# Sanity + Next.js on Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify, sanity

Totally lost here. I am building a website using Sanity as backend, Next.js as frontend and deploying it on netlify for production.
However, cant get it to work.

Does anybody have a link to an up-to-date article explaining how to deploy such project?

Issues I am facing are:

1. When trying to deploy next.js app on netlify it doesnt render styling and js logic. I only get HTML.
2. cant figure out how to add sanity studio to my deployment. Followed a few articles on found on internet (and some articles on sanity website) but seems like all of them are outdated so none of then worked.
   For some reason my react version in sanity project is 17, however in next js project its 18. When i tried to run NPM install in sanity project i got errors:

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! sanity-plugin-dashboard-widget-netlify@"^1.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @sanity/ui@0.36.17

However, everything works OK on localhost.

3. how should i deploy my project? I have 2 folders in there. One is called Studio - this is my sanity studio (backend). 2nd is called Web. This is NextJs app - my front end.

Please, let know what info do u need from me. I am not even sure what else i can share here to make it easier for you to help me. I guess i just need to understand how Sanity-nextjs-netlify deployment works in general

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround,

- use `npx sanity build public` ,
- and type `n` to not delete public in terminal,
- after that changed the index.html to studio.html in public.
- now add this in netlify.toml,

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/studio/*"
  to = "/studio.html"
  status = 301
  force = true
```

just normal deploy and try to access by /studio